# NEW URL generated and cannot access to it

Tags: cypress

I have a process that create a quote divided in different test cases:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34l4W.png)

in the first IT I have the cy.visit which visit the login page of my page filling it with user and password
"the issue appears when I submit " I got a new URL generated and what I assumed is that it is not linking to the new url so the process stuck and cannot continue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0cC8.png)

so after that I got the error that the page cannot proceed, it stuck and get back to the login page and dont proceed with the other page generated automatically:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTDfa.png)

Well I am new in Cypress automation so I am not sure what is going on after I login on my page it get stuck in the process going back to the login page. So I am kind of sure it is not linking into the new URL that has the same domain so any person who has knowledge in Cypress can help me

Answer (score 3):

It is the way Cypress works to stop one test contaminating the next one, and giving you a false pass.

The way you need to handle is with a session command to keep your login credential renewed for each test.

This is the pattern:

```js
describe('before logged in', () => {
  it("Login into the system", function () {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env("ur146b"));
    //login
    login.getUser().type(this.data.user);
    login.getPass().type(this.data.pass);
    login.getLogin().click();
    cy.wait(1000);
  });
})

describe('when logged in', () => {
  // now make such the login is renewed for each test
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.session('login', () => {
      cy.visit(Cypress.env("ur146b"));
      //login
      login.getUser().type(this.data.user);
      login.getPass().type(this.data.pass);
      login.getLogin().click();
    })
  })

  it("Menu - full quote - get client", function () {
    cy.visit('/homepage');
    menu.getPolicy().click();
    menu.getQuote().click();
    menu.getClient().click();
    cy.wait(1000);
  });

  it("fill client and address info", function () {  
    cy.visit('/homepage');
    ...
  });
})
```

Read the complete details [documentation page](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session)

---

Sorry I missed one step - it is mandatory to use `cy.visit()` in each test block after adding `cy.session()` to the login.

Otherwise you get the "blank page" problem you mention.

Ref [session](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session)

> Because the page is cleared at the beginning of each test by default, `cy.visit()` must be explicitly called at the beginning of each test.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1doYz.png)
I make the changes on my code also I added on cypress.config :experimentalSessionAndOrigin: true

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWuTq.png)
I did my research and I got that the page is in blank and not showing the after login page

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).